# Кроссбраузерные r/o переменные

Tags: prototype, getter, javascript, setter

Есть вот такой пример:

```
function RECT(w, h) {
    //w и h задаются только в конструкторе
    Object.defineProperty(this, 'w', {
        get: function () {
            return w;
        }
    });
    Object.defineProperty(this, 'h', {
        get: function () {
            return h;
        }
    });
}
//перемножить, задавать нельзя вообще.
Object.defineProperty(RECT.prototype, "area", {
    get: function () {
        return this.w * this.h;
    },
    set: function (val) {
        throw("no no no");
    }
});

var rectangle = new RECT(45, 10);
var rectangle2 = new RECT(41, 10);
rectangle.w = 10;
console.log(rectangle.area);
console.log(rectangle2.area);
rectangle.area=1;
alert('а до сюда не дойдём');
```

но это не будет работать в IE, как-бы такое сделать чтобы хотя-бы с IE7 работало ?

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/XEzBc/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Еще в старых версиях IE можно попробовать сэмулирувать сеттеры\геттеры посредством watch'еров через onpropertychange у DOM-элементов. Но, разумеется получится весьма извращенно. http://webreflection.blogspot.ru/2009/01/internet-explorer-object-watch.html

Comment: прикольно, но там часть геттера реализована в сеттере, что нечестно. (скорее даже getter не реализован, просто setter)

Comment: вопрос read-only решает, с другой стороны, хотя, надо понять, смогу ли я это наследовать, ведь в прототип то не запихнешь watch.

Answer (score 2):

В IE8 и ниже не поддерживаются геттеры и сеттеры. Но есть их извращённая [реализация](http://habrahabr.ru/post/75158/)

Comment: совсем уж извращенный, есть вот это http://johndyer.name/native-browser-get-set-properties-in-javascript/ пытаюсь выдумать как это применить к прототипам.

Comment: Лучше не использовать встроенные get/set, это сильно ухудшает читабельность кода и отладку. 
Лучше использовать явные методы getProp(), setProp(), которым кстати можно добавить параметры, чего нету в get/set

Comment: так не скрыть переменные иначе чем через eval. Если я вас правильно понял. (ну или все методы придется в конструкторе инициализировать как `this.getProp=function(){};` )

Comment: вот так нормально делать то что вы сказали ? http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/SX9Ew/

Comment: Что-то у вас всё сложно получилось, ещё зачем-то устаревший arguments.callee используете.

Вот же:

function MyClass()
{
};

MyClass.prototype.getProp = function()
{
    return this._Prop;
};

MyClass.prototype.setProp= function(v)
{
    this._Prop = v;
};

Comment: а как вы закроете доступ к this._Prop ? без calee ? Зачем это нужно ? вот за этим например http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/SX9Ew/3/

Comment: Чтобы понимать что это скрытое поле, я используй префикс _, а скрывать так чтобы вообще вообще нельзя было достучаться не вижу смысла, да и отлаживать проблематично такие объекты